# Full page screenshot with Selenium Chrome driver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

AI insists that for Selenium 4 or later to take the full page screenshot with `webdriver.Chrome()`, you can use the 'full' argument in `driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png", full=True)`.
However, I get error message

> TypeError: WebDriver.get_screenshot_as_file() got an unexpected
> keyword argument 'full'

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message does a pretty good job here: WebDriver.get_screenshot_as_file() does not have a keyword argument called 'full'.

Here is a method I have used in the past:

```
def save_screenshot():
    original_size = driver.get_window_size()
    required_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
    required_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
    driver.set_window_size(required_width, required_height)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(path)
    driver.set_window_size(original_size['width'], original_size['height'])
```

Comment: Thank you, @samsupertaco. I knew the solution with JavaScript, but what AI suggested looked simpler with one statement. However, I could not find any description for the parameter 'full'. But for Firefox, you can get the full page screenshot with one statement: driver.save_full_page_screenshot(file).

Comment: Yeah, I believe that solution only works for firefox. I do not think there is something that elegant for other browsers.